# How to eliminate outstanding values in python?

Tags: python

I have an array of zeros and ones which are intended to be of some defined width. It's a processed signal and some spikes suddenly appear during processing. I want to get rid of this spikes just to set them to the same values as surrending elements are set to.

[image: The plot of my array]

I did what I wanted in a simple way like this:

```
for ind, x in enumerate(signal_bool):
    if ind == 0 or ind == len(signal_bool) - 1:
        continue

    if signal_bool[ind-1] == signal_bool[ind+1]:
        signal_bool[ind] = signal_bool[ind-1]
```

But I'm curious if there is any eloquent way to obtain the same result.

Comment: What you're looking for is called a *median filter*.

Comment: Is `signal_bool` a numpy array, a pandas Series or a plain old list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it helps.

if signal_bool is pd.Series:

```
ind = signal_bool.shift(-1) == signal_bool.shift(1)
signal_bool[ind] = signal_bool.shift(-1)[ind]
```

if signal_bool is numpy:

```
ind = np.roll(signal_bool, -1) == np.roll(signal_bool, 1)
signal_bool[ind] = np.roll(signal_bool, -1)[ind]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the code a bit:

```py
for ind in range(1, len(signal_bool) - 1):
    if signal_bool[ind - 1] == signal_bool[ind + 1]:
        signal_bool[ind] = signal_bool[ind - 1]
```

This approach removes the `enumerate` and first `if/continue` statement, since `range` will only operate on the middle indexes.